# I'm looking for the simplest way to integrate generating a serial number and e-mailing AFTER a PayPal purchase

Tags: paypal, download

I'm trying to integrate creating a serial#/key AFTER a user has purchased a software download using PayPal and e-mailing it to the user.

I have a PayPal Developer account, and I have looked at some of their docs, but I'm a bit overwhelmed by all the options. I assume I have to use a webhook...

So I'm looking for some guidance on HOW to add the following functionality to my WEB site.

1. User Clicks PayPal Button Link
2. User makes transaction
3. Website generates a serial# and e-mails to the user
4. Database is updated with user e-mail and serial info

Somewhere I guess I need to create a form for the user's e-mail, BEFORE the PayPal link.

Any sample code would be appreciated. The PayPal link works fine, I just don't know how to proceed.

(I have looked at several responses here, but none seem to address EXACTLY what I'm trying to do)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

PayPal transactions always have an email address associated with them. Do you want to use the email they paid with?

If not, you could collect another separate email address as part of the PayPal transaction, storing it in the `custom_id` field. Use a function to retrieve the value, such as `document.getElementById(...).value`

Since you want to send an e-mail and update a database, use a server integration. Create two routes, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return JSON data when called. The latter can (on success) send the email and update the database before returning its JSON.

Pair your two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look...

I think I'm probably making this more difficult than it actually is - using the PayPal e-mail should be sufficient...